# Refactoring components to a shared location in Svelte Kit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

There are some Svelte components that we're using at different Svelte Kit applications, and we need to put them at a shared location.

We have something like this right now:

```
/frontend (which is a SvelteKit app)
/backend (which is a SvelteKit app)
/shared (which is just a folder)
```

In `/shared`, we have very basic components like icons that we use from both `/frontend` and `/backend`. We even defined an alias at both apps so we can use `$shared` to reference those component's location. This works perfectly.

Right now we want to refactor a more complex component from one of the apps to the `shared` location so it can be used also from the other app. But with this component, I also need to have an Svelte store, or use node libraries. The Svelte store needs to be accesable from the apps (frontend and backend).

A) Should I have the store and the libraries at the main apps (frontend and backend) and reference to them from `/shared`?

B) Should I install a complete SvelteKit in `/shared` so I'm able to use stores, libraries, and so on at that place?

If the answer is B:

1- I prefer not "building" the shared components, because I'm not publishing them to anywhere. I would prefer just "importing" them. How should I export them from the shared app?

2- Should I have problems if versions of Svelte or Kit diverge from the ones in `/shared` to the ones in the other apps?

Comment: I would go with B, I would do it by creating a npm package (they can be private) and add you lib as a npm package in both project. This way you can have a svelte dependencies in your lib (just install the ones you need, maybe don't create an entire svelkit app).